# Tailwind CSS isn't showing up on my browser

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I've installed Tailwind CSS into my React App and I fixed some initial problems related to my `settings.json` file. Then, I had no issues, no errors were popping up on VS Code, and I was able to use Tailwind in VS Code with ease. However, I can't see anything applied on my local server...it looks the same  I've reinstalled Tailwind multiple times, done tester apps, gone through every answer possible on Stack, Git & Discord and still can't find a solution.

This is the output I see on my local server, despite adding some basic Tailwind classes: [https://prnt.sc/tPwr5Q0g7nMP]

This is my directory structure: [https://prnt.sc/SrCgXh61VKxo]

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.html,js",
    "./UI/**/*.html,js",
    "./pages/**/*.js"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const el = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(el);

root.render(<App />);
```

**index.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**app.js**

```
import ProfileCard from './UI/ProfileCard';
import AlexaImage from './images/alexa.png';
import CortanaImage from './images/cortana.png';
import SiriImage from './images/siri.png';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Personal Digital Assistants</div>

      <ProfileCard title="Alexa" handle="@alexa99" image={AlexaImage} />
      <ProfileCard title="Cortana" handle="@cortana32" image={CortanaImage} />
      <ProfileCard title="Siri" handle="@siri01" image={SiriImage} />

      <TailwindCSSButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function TailwindCSSButton(){
  return(
    <button className="bg-black">Save Changes</button>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**ProfileCard.js**

```
import React from "react";

function ProfileCard({ title, handle, image }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-400 border-black" flex>
      <img src={image} alt="pda logo" />
      <div className='font-semibold'>Title is {title}</div>
      <div>Handle is {handle}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProfileCard;
```

I have Tailwind installed and I'm sure the content configuration is set up. This has been driving me insane for over 6 hours, please can someone help! :)

Comment: I was being stupid... And AI called me out on it ha! I forgot to add the index.css file to my index.js file - I should've had that coffee...

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.) Import css to app

`import './<path>/index.css'` to `app.js` or `index.js`

#### 2.) Syntax

**BAD**

```json
content: [
  "./src/**/*.html,js",
  "./UI/**/*.html,js",
  "./pages/**/*.js"
],
```

**GOOD**

```json
content: [
  "./src/**/*.html",
  "./src/**/*.js",
  "./UI/**/*.html",
  "./UI/**/*.js",
  "./pages/**/*.js"
],
```

Or if you like short code, use `{` and `}`:

```json
content: [
  "./src/**/*.{html,js}",
  "./UI/**/*.{html,js}",
  "./pages/**/*.js"
],
```

More information for this can find [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation). (second step)

Comment: Thanks for the response :) - I've tried both of those, plus gone through the second step on Tailwind.css, but the output on the browser is still the same, unfortunately.